# guid entropy on virtual machines

Tags: winapi, guid, entropy

What does `CoCreateGuid` in ole32.dll (used by `Guid.NewGuid()` in .NET) use to get entropy for it's psudo-random number generator?

At a guess I suspect it uses `rand` or `rand_s` but it may use `CryptGenRandom` to get higher entropy.

What I am mainly wondering do virtual machines running on the same physical machine share any of this entropy?

I know that RFC4122 doesn't state that guids need to be truly random (only unique), are there any elements of this entropy implementation that could be easily obtained and used to determine guids in the future?

I'm mostly interested if running an application on multiple virtual machines that are hosted on the same physical machine will be more incline to generate guid collisions.

For the most part we can assume we are dealing with v4 guids and not v1 (which contain the mac address as part of their generation)

Comment: This is all pretty academic when nobody can look at the source code.  And the few that do are not allowed to disclose anything.  SO guidelines do demand that you describe the problem you are trying to solve, I don't see one.

Comment: @Hans Passant: The question is quite clear and not academic at all: Seph is wants to know if a (closed-source) function provided by Microsoft meets his requirements (GUIDs must be worldwide unique) or if he has to implement this function himself because the function does not meet his requirements.